# How can I do update method based on condition?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django project and I want to proceed to update method based on condition - if value of requeststatusid = 0 only. I've tried adding errorhandling in my serializers, but no matter the value is, it throws the error. Appreciate any help!

Here is my serializer with create and update method. See my if/else condition in update.

```
class RequestCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        parts=PartSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
            model = requestTable
            fields = ['rid','requestid', 'requeststatusid', 'requesterid', 'requestname', 'parts']
            parts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ​
        def create(self, validated_data):
            parts_data = validated_data.pop('parts')
            request = requestTable.objects.create(**validated_data)
            for part_data in parts_data:
                partsTable.objects.create(request=request, **part_data)
            return request
    ​
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    ​
            if instance.requeststatusid == '0':
                parts_data = validated_data.pop('parts')
                part = (instance.parts).all()
                part = list(part)
                instance.requeststatusid = validated_data.get('requeststatusid', instance.requeststatusid)
                instance.requestname = validated_data.get('requestname', instance.requestname)
                instance.save()
    ​
                for part_data in parts_data:
                    partreq = part.pop()
                    partreq.validatorid = part_data.get('validatorid', partreq.validatorid)
                    partreq.partsstatusid = part_data.get('partsstatusid', partreq.partsstatusid)
                    partreq.englishmaterialdescription = part_data.get('englishmaterialdescription', partreq.englishmaterialdescription)
                    partreq.save()
                return instance
    ​
            else:
                raise ValidationError({"Error": 'Non-drafts are non-editable.'})
    ​
    ​
    //views.py
    class RequestListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = requestTable.objects.all()
        serializer_class = RequestCreateSerializer
        filterset_class = RequestFilter
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter]
    ​
        filterset_fields=['rid', 'requeststatusid']
        search_fields= ['requestname', 'requestid', 'businessunitid__businessunitname', 'plantid__plantname', 'parts__partsid']
    ​
        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            write_serializer = RequestCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
            write_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            instance = self.perform_create(write_serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(write_serializer.data)
            return Response({"Request ID": write_serializer.instance.requestid, "Parts ID": [p.partsid for p in write_serializer.instance.parts.all()]},headers=headers)
    ​
        def get_queryset(self):
             return requestTable.objects.exclude(requeststatusid='0').exclude(requeststatusid='4')
    ​
```

Here is a sample data:​

```
{
        "rid": 4,
        "requestid": "ABC0000004",
        "requeststatusid": 0,
        "requestname": "Draft",
        "projectmanager": "Manager"
        "parts": [
            {
                "pid": 7,
                "partsid": "ABC0000007",
                "validatorid": "bcdd5f90-8e4a-4306-b2fe-1ea3218ee430",
                "partsstatusid": 0,
                "englishmaterialdescription": "Prefilter element FRP-95-115",
            }
        ]
    }
```

Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /api/putRequest/request/4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response        
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view       
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception  
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 285, in put
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\project\api\views.py", line 55, in update
    response = super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 68, in update
    self.perform_update(serializer)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 78, in perform_update
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 207, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\user\project\api\serializers.py", line 60, in update
    raise ValidationError({"Error": 'Non-drafts are non-editable.'})
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'Error': ['Non-drafts are non-editable.']}
```

Comment: can you share error log?

Comment: you sure about data type its str? `instance.requeststatusid` if its int then it will execute else part

Comment: I made it if `instance.requeststatusid == 0:` but it still throws the same error @HemalPatel

Comment: can you try this and share the output? `print("id",instance.requeststatusid, type(instance.requeststatusid))`before if condition

Comment: if it's to verify the data type, requeststatusid is integerfield @HemalPatel

Comment: then it won't skip if condition. is it directly raising an error or trying to execute if block as well?

Comment: it's just raising an error and not executing if block :/ @HemalPatel

Comment: weird, can you share git repo if its meant for learning purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I notice you are comparing '0' with 0 (str with int) for that it go to else statment `raise ValidationError({"Error": 'Non-drafts are non-editable.'})`

make it `if instance.requeststatusid == 0:` because in your request it is 0 as **int**

Comment: I tried it but it's still sending the same error @hashem

Comment: try to do it in this way instance.requeststatusid = validated_data.get('requeststatusid', instance.requeststatusid) after that apply the condation

Comment: still strangely not working :/ @hashem